# Uploaded image is not save to a folder

Tags: php, file-upload

I've html upload form which process by image-crop.php. I want to save the image to img folder after upload is done. But it's not save the image to img folder. Any suggestions why image is not save to that folder ?

**Html form:**

```
<form action="image-crop-demo.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Upload an image for processing<br>
    <input type="file" name="Image1"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Upload">
</form>
```

**Php code:**

```
define('DESIRED_IMAGE_WIDTH', 200);
define('DESIRED_IMAGE_HEIGHT', 200);
$source_path = $_FILES['Image1']['tmp_name'];
list($source_width, $source_height, $source_type) = getimagesize($source_path);

switch ($source_type) {
    case IMAGETYPE_GIF:
        $source_gdim = imagecreatefromgif($source_path);
        break;
    case IMAGETYPE_JPEG:
        $source_gdim = imagecreatefromjpeg($source_path);
        break;
    case IMAGETYPE_PNG:
        $source_gdim = imagecreatefrompng($source_path);
        break;
}

$source_aspect_ratio = $source_width / $source_height;
$desired_aspect_ratio = DESIRED_IMAGE_WIDTH / DESIRED_IMAGE_HEIGHT;

if ($source_aspect_ratio > $desired_aspect_ratio) {
    $temp_height = DESIRED_IMAGE_HEIGHT;
    $temp_width = ( int ) (DESIRED_IMAGE_HEIGHT * $source_aspect_ratio);
} else {
    $temp_width = DESIRED_IMAGE_WIDTH;
    $temp_height = ( int ) (DESIRED_IMAGE_WIDTH / $source_aspect_ratio);
}

$temp_gdim = imagecreatetruecolor($temp_width, $temp_height);
imagecopyresampled(
    $temp_gdim,
    $source_gdim,
    0, 0,
    0, 0,
    $temp_width, $temp_height,
    $source_width, $source_height
);

$x0 = ($temp_width - DESIRED_IMAGE_WIDTH) / 2;
$y0 = ($temp_height - DESIRED_IMAGE_HEIGHT) / 2;
$desired_gdim = imagecreatetruecolor(DESIRED_IMAGE_WIDTH, DESIRED_IMAGE_HEIGHT);
imagecopy(
    $desired_gdim,
    $temp_gdim,
    0, 0,
    $x0, $y0,
    DESIRED_IMAGE_WIDTH, DESIRED_IMAGE_HEIGHT
);

header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
imagejpeg($desired_gdim, "img/", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are incorrectly passing second parameter:

```
imagejpeg($desired_gdim, "img/", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
                               ^--- THE COMMA SHOULD NOT BE THERE
```

and probably you need to pass an absolute path, not a relative one, so try this:

```
imagejpeg($desired_gdim, $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."img/".$_FILES["file"]["name"]);
```

Comment: It's not save the image to img folder.

Comment: If i use this- imagejpeg($desired_gdim); then it's show a image after upload is done but i want to save to img folder.